# Cannot implicitly convert type 'project_name.Models.model_name' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I want to print only the articles with `(ShowInDatabase == true)`
but I encounter:

> RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'PROIECT.Models.Article' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) in Views->Articles->Index : @foreach (PROIECT.Models.Article article in ViewBag.Articles)

In Model->Article there is this

```cs
public bool ShowInDatabase { get; set; }
```

The query:

```cs
var articles = db.Articles.Include("Domain").Include("User")
    .Where(art=> art.ShowInDatabase == true)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

IMPORTANT: If I modify the query like this, it works:

```cs
var articles = db.Articles.Include("Domain").Include("User");
```

Send to View via

```cs
ViewBag.Articles = articles;
```

In Views->Articles->Index

```
@foreach (project_name.Models.Article article in ViewBag.Articles)
```

Answer (score 2):

A single object and a *collection* of objects are two different things.  To put it another way... An apple is not a basket of apples.

Here you're fetching a single instance of an object:

```
var articles = db.Articles.Include("Domain").Include("User")
                 .Where(art=> art.ShowInDatabase == true)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

You can't loop over it, because it's not a collection.  It's a single object.

So you essentially have two options:

1. Don't loop over the object, just use it directly.
2. Fetch a collection of objects instead of a single one.  For example:

```
var articles = db.Articles.Include("Domain").Include("User")
                 .Where(art=> art.ShowInDatabase == true);
```